# Loading a "special" MFC control from a Satellite DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have an MFC application using satellites DLLs in order to support the multilingualism. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

I am able to change the language of the core part of the application without any problems. Things go wrong when I try to load a modeless dialog containing a "special" MFC control (`CMFCColorButton`, `CVSListBox`, etc).

The problem occurs at the following statement :

```
m_dlg->Create(SOME_IID, this); // returns false
```

How should I proceed to load a "special" MFC control from a satellite DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must register their classes before you reach `OnCreate()`. For custom controls, this is typically done in the constructor:

```
CMyClass::CMyClass()
{
    // Pseudo code
    m_mfcColorButton.RegisterWindowClass(AfxGetResourceHandle());
}
```

For MFC controls, I bet there is an initialization function that needs to be called.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: my CDialog - derived class failed in DoModal if I use localized resource dll. It contains CMFCColorButton on resource template.

My solution was to call in a **resource dll** AfxRegisterMFCCtrlClasses();

```
class CMyApp: public CWinApp
{
    BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        AfxRegisterMFCCtrlClasses();
        return CWinApp::InitInstance();
    }
};
```